# Python: setLevel of specific class's logger

Tags: python, class, logging

How do I silence a class's logging without knowing the name of its logger? Class in question is [qualysconnect](https://bitbucket.org/uWaterloo_IST_ISS/python-qualysconnect).

```
import logging
import qualysconnect.util

# Set log options. This is my attempt to silence it.
logger_qc = logging.getLogger('qualysconnect')
logger_qc.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# Define a Handler which writes WARNING messages or higher to the sys.stderr
logger_console = logging.StreamHandler()
logger_console.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
# Set a format which is simpler for console use.
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# Tell the handler to use this format.
logger_console.setFormatter(formatter)
# Add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(logger_console)

# 'application' code
logging.debug('debug message')
logging.info('info message')
logging.warn('warn message')
logging.error('error message')
logging.critical('critical message')
```

Output when `import qualysconnect.util` is commented out:

```
root        : ERROR    error message
root        : CRITICAL critical message
```

Output when `import qualysconnect.util` is kept in:

```
WARNING:root:warn message
ERROR:root:error message
root        : ERROR    error message
CRITICAL:root:critical message
root        : CRITICAL critical message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, as they did not define a name for their logger, and as in `qualysconnect.util` they don't even do a `getLogger` call or a `getChild` call, you can't do something on one that will not affect the whole module's logging behavior without getting dirty.

The only clean option I can think of is to report the way they handle logging as a bug, and submit a patch request where you modify `qualysconnect.util` logging statement with something like:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('qualysconnect').getChild('util')
```

and replace all `logging.info()`, `logging.debug()`... into `logger.info()`, `logger.debug()`...

The dirty option: You can monkey patch the `qualysconnect.util` module so you replace its `logging` object with a logger object:

```
import qualysconnect.util
logger_qc = logging.getLogger('qualysconnect')
logger_qc.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
qualysconnect.util.logging = logger_qc.getLogger('qualysconnect').getChild('util')
qualysconnect.util.logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL) # will disable all logging for CRITICAL and below
```

That can be a working solution for the time you're sending a patch request to the upstream project, but certainly not a long-term working solution.

Or you can simply shut all logging off from the whole `qualysconnect` module, but I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: I am a contributor to the source and I suspected that this was the solution: https://bitbucket.org/uWaterloo_IST_ISS/python-qualysconnect/issue/19/set-logger-name

Comment: Thank you so much for your confirmation!

Comment: Created my own class qualysapi. Trying to implement a package level logging. Any advice?